# Dropdown menu slideup goes too fast

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

**My Solution:**

I use this:
http://www.kriesi.at/archives/create-a-multilevel-dropdown-menu-with-css-and-improve-it-via-jquery

And here on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nBKZ9/

**Thank you guys for your help!**

I have this drop down menu, which works with this little code:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#menu-headermenu li > .sub-menu').parent().hover(function(){             
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').stop(true).slideToggle(400);              
        });
    });
```

The problem is, if the mouse goes too fast the sub menus are closing before I can hover them with the mouse.

For better understanding I made this video which I uploaded on youtube:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlRJHkK5-u8

EDIT://
http://jsfiddle.net/gLDu2/

Comment: instead of video show a jsfiddle..

Comment: You can increase the time of an animation like `.slideToggle()` by increasing the number passed into it. Alternatively, you can also increase the delay of the animation by using `.delay(time)` where time is in milliseconds.

Comment: Sorry i don't know this. Here it the Link: http://jsfiddle.net/gLDu2/

Comment: Try `$(this).children('.sub-menu').stop(true).delay(500).slideToggle(400);`

Comment: delay made it worse. You can try it in jsfiddle :/

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using jQuery to do this? Why not use CSS transitions?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the time from 400 to 900?...http://jsfiddle.net/gLDu2/1/

Comment: No. I never used it before. But i will have a look at this.

Comment: ahh.. this is a really messy design to begin with... I would just try to link everything together and put it closer.. this is going to cause people a headache down the road.

Comment: Consider something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/gLDu2/2/

Comment: Consider Kamen's [jQuery-menu-aim](https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim) plugin. It can make navigating from a menu item to a sub-menu item significantly more usable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to use:

```
$('#menu-headermenu li > .sub-menu').parent().hover
```

Just use:

```
$('#menu-headermenu li').hover
```

Second of all, .delay does work. Check out the updated fiddle, where the event is delayed for 1000ms (1 second):

http://jsfiddle.net/gLDu2/3/

Comment: You can change the .delay(1000) to something longer or shorter depending on how long you want to wait before the event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way: http://jsfiddle.net/qphEE/1/

```
$('#menu-headermenu').find('.menu-item-has-children').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideDown(400);
}, function () {
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideUp(400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution for my problem:

There is a known issue with the jQuery slideUp/slideDown functions and no set height. Ensure the element to be hidden has a specified height.

ALSO, the min-height css property will futz things up. Remove min-height from the element.

Reference:

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/slideup-slow-and-slidedown-slow-happening-instantly